# HTML/css/Javascript cloud slide

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate, cloud

So, I am trying to create an effect similar to the clouds on this website: http://www.poweredwebsite.com/index-v.php
How exactly would I do this using either html, css, or javascript?

Comment: Well,there is nothing giving a tutorial on something similar on the internet, and I tried a few things but none of them came even close to producing that effect, so I deleted the code for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a repeating background image and animate the x position with jQuery:

The HTML could be whatever you want:

```
<div class="banner">
  <!-- etc. -->
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.banner {
  height: 200px;
  width: 800px;
  background: url(path/to/image);
}
```

And some jQuery:

```
function animateBanner() {
  jQuery('.banner').css({
    backgroundPositionX: '0'
  }).animate({
    backgroundPositionX: '-400px'
  }, 5000, 'linear', animateBanner);
}
animateBanner();
```

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tLEBa/

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4vrgdWkw That is my code and it isnt working (Forgive me, I suck at jQuery.)

Comment: It looks like you're working with `<img>` elements instead of background images. In that case, you'll want to animate the `left` property instead of `backgroundPositionX`. See vov's answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Taking what **Brandon** suggested and advancing it step further, I came up with a possible working solution utilizing jquery's animate function:

```
    function animate() {
$( ".banner" ).animate({ "left": "+=400px" }, 3000, "linear",
                       function() {$(this).css({ "left": "-=400px" });
animate();
        } );
}

animate();
```

please see the following snippet:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tLEBa/63/)

The suggested solution uses two images, positioned side by side horizontally.
Both images x coordinate is interpolated linearly to achieve wrap effect.
Notice that you will need a seamless image for a good match.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4vrgdWkw Still doesnt work! PLEASE take a look at my code and tell me what is wrong!

Comment: The "scroll-image" css class definition is missing in your code.